# c# - ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range - 2 Forms

Tags: c#

Problem solved.

The original "private void buttonSave_Click" was changed to:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList.Count != 100)
    {
        MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList.Add(new Album(NameTextBox.Text));

        MessageBox.Show("New Album added: " + NameTextBox.Text);
        formMain.ListAlbums(formMain.AlbumsListBox.Items);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No room for new album.");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Original Post:

I'm new to using C#, so appologies for any seemly obvious mistakes or terrible coding.

I'm trying to create a new Album object (that gets its Name from NameTextBox.Text on Form FormAlbumAC) and add it to List AlbumList when the user clicks the save button on FormAlbumAC. Then I want to list all of AlbumList in a ListBox on Form FormMain.

When I run the program and click the save button, I'm getting the error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled, Index was out of range" at the line:

```
if (MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList[i] == null)
// line 8 on my excerpt from Form FormAblumAC
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Form FormMain:

```
public const int MAX_ALBUMS = 100;
public int totalAlbums = 0;

public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public static class PublicVars
{
    public static List<Album> AlbumList { get; set; }

    static PublicVars()
    {
        AlbumList = new List<Album>(MAX_ALBUMS);
    }
}

public ListBox AlbumListBox
{
    get
    {
        return AlbumListBox;
    }
}

public void ListAlbums(IList list)
{
    list.Clear();
    foreach (var album in PublicVars.AlbumList)
    {
        if (album == null)
            continue;
        list.Add(album.Name);
    }
}
```

Form FormAlbumAC:

```
private FormMain formMain;

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MusicCollection.FormMain.MAX_ALBUMS; ++i)
    {
        if (MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList[i] == null)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index != -1)
    {
        MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList[index] = new Album(NameTextBox.Text);
        ++formMain.totalAlbums;

        MessageBox.Show("New Album added: " + NameTextBox.Text);
        formMain.ListAlbums(formMain.AlbumsListBox.Items);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No room for new album.");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post where you declare `MAX_ABUMS`?

Comment: Right at the beginning of FormMain, sorry, will add.

Comment: Right, but we need to see the code. The conditional statement in that for loop is suspicious, and I think your problem has to do with what you've declared `MAX_ALBUMS` to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (from your comments) is that your for loop's condition is incorrect. Your for loop is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MusicCollection.FormMain.MAX_ALBUMS; ++i)
```

There is one problem and one potential problem here. First, when this code is actually run, it's really running:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
```

because `MusicCollection.FormMain.MAX_ALBUMS` is declared as 100. This causes an error when the length of `MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList` is less than 100, because you're trying to grab an index that doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to iterate from `i=0` to the length of `....PublicVars.AlbumList-1`, or, preferably, `for(int i = 0; i < ....PublicVars.AlbumList.Count; i++)`.

The second potential problem is that you are potentially skipping index 0. Arrays start at index zero and continue to index `length-1`. As such, you probably want `i++`, not `++i`. Depends on your implementation, though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the error is actually occuring at the line below. I copied the wrong line, but mentioned the right line below it. Thank you for the advise though, I've made those changes.

Comment: That's where the error should be happening, actually. It should be cleared (I'm making an edit to my answer, though. Should be the length of AlbumList minus 1.)

Comment: Ok, changed "for (int i = 0; i < MusicCollection.FormMain.MAX_ALBUMS; i++)" to "for (int i = 0; i < MusicCollection.FormMain.PublicVars.AlbumList.Count; i++)". I now have the message box "MessageBox.Show("No room for new album.");" (Ln 25 FormAlbumAC excerpt) pop up.

Comment: You need to rethink your conditionals and logic flow towards the bottom.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is actually find a null space in the list. Once I've found it I then want to bookmark it with index and break from searching. Then, now that index is not -1, I want to do all the stuff in "if (index != -1) {... }". So the above solution means I'm actually never going to find a null right?

Comment: Right, well, that isn't what it seemed like you were asking. I _strongly_ recommend not doing it that way. If you do, though, verify that your album list is _actually_ 100 indexes long. Remember, there's a difference between accessing an empty index and accessing an nonexistent one.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting an exception for a null when I'm intentionally trying to find and fill one. I've just done a check with message boxes and I know that the count of AlbumList = 0, and the Capacity = 100 (now I've set it). So it exists and it has room. Can you suggest a good way of finding an empty space in AlbumList and adding a new Album?

Comment: Add new entries to AlbumList, don't search for empty ones. I've answered your question as best I can; if you need further help, I would suggest working on it a little first, then posting another question if you are truly stuck.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I had been treating the List like I had been taught to use arrays. With .Count I found I could really simplify "private void buttonSave_Click".